# when Uv unwrapping and texture painting something goes wrong with the objects and i get triangular shapes everywhere

Tags: uv

i recently started to learn how to sculpt in blender and now that i'm happy of the person I created i wanted to texture paint. following a youtube tutorial the guy told me to uv unwrap it and then just paint it.
I painted it completly but now i have these weird triangular shapes all over my object...
[image: problem with the object]
is there anything i can do to get rid of them?

thanks in advance